# Getting built environment within administrative areas from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, layers, overpass-api

I have a collection of all administrative boundaries (level 8) in a country. I am interested in playing with the shapes of these towns and cities using Python (shapely, osmnx). But I would like to consider only "inhabited" or "built" parts of the towns. Specifically, I would like to extract the polygon of the grey (but dark and light areas from the administrative polygon (purple dotted line) in overpass.  [image: Town Grey Areas]

So far I have tried the buildings API without luck. Is there a specific name for this layer? Once I figure out how to extract this layer I could follow a post like [How to Intersect between a vector (administrative areas) and a raster layer (slope)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44844/how-to-intersect-between-a-vector-administrative-areas-and-a-raster-layer-slo) to obtain the intersection, though I am also happy to hear if someone knows of a slick way to to do this all via Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a specific name for this layer?

The "grey" areas you are referring to are tipically tagged as [`landuse=residential`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:landuse%3Dresidential). You might also be interested in `landuse=commercial` and `landuse=industrial`.

Please note that OSM does not really have a tag for "built-up" areas/features.

I suggest you download a OSM dataset for landuse, and try making some intersections between the administrative polygons and their land uses.

Comment: thank you! Do you think this is possible with an overpass query like this (plus filtering for the specific landuses you mention)?:
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “"land use"”
  area[name="Hungary"];
  way["landuse"]({{bbox}});
  relation["landuse"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;